# When you click android app, which class is stared first among android framework

Tags: android

I want to know HOW Android works from when I click and launch an Android App.

When I started android programming, I learned "Activity.java" is the starting point. But that's just from perspective of users and programmar.

What I want to know is how it works from **INSIDE ANDROID**.

I've realized there are "Application.java," "ContextImple.java" and "ActivityThread.java" before Activity class.

WHICH of these classes first started when user click an app Icon to launch it??

Were there any other classes executed in advance?
If any, what are they,  and what makes it started?

Comment: What is the purpose behind this question? Please post the reason if possible.

Comment: ActivityThread > ContextImpl (for Application) > Application, you can read the source code of [ActivityThread](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java) and find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Android is a Linux based OS almost every application run in its own [process](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#Processes), this process is created by Android when some of application's code need to be run. A big difference between Android and other Linux distributions is that application process's lifetime is controlled by the OS.

The Entry point to an application is a component which can started either by the user or system. The [`Application`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) class, or your subclass of the Application class, is instantiated before any other class when the process for your application/package is created.

There are four different types of app components:

- Activities
- Services
- Broadcast receivers
- Content providers

App launch can take place in one of three states:

- **Cold Start:** app’s starting from scratch, the system has three task:

  1. Loading and launching the app.
  2. Displaying a blank starting window for the app immediately after launch.
  3. Creating the app process.
     And just after the process has been created, it's responsible for the next stages:

     1. Creating the app object.
     2. Launching the main thread.
     3. Creating the main activity.
     4. Inflating views.
     5. Laying out the screen.
     6. Performing the initial draw.

  [image: cold lunch]
- **Hot Start:** bring your activity to the foreground
- **Warm Start:** encompasses some subset of the operations that take place during a cold start

**Conclusion:** To build an efficient application it is important to know how Android behave through the lifetime of the application process. If you want to have a deep understanding about how Android handle things like memory management (which I think is not necessary for android application development) you have to first know about how Linux works and then try to understand Android source code

There is a full reference [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time) in Android Developers